# How i can recreate this effect 3D

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d, styles

Hi i been looking a webpage and i found out a a website with beautiful effect ,here is the link  [Beautifl effect](http://www.chromazone-imaging.co.uk/flashindex.html)

I like recreate these multi layers of background and when the mouse move you see a beautiful, almost 3D, illusion going on. The shapes seem to move in a fluid like motion in 3D, a fake perspective illusion has been created.

Of Course i wish recreate this effect with Wpf and Blend ,sincerely i'm a beginner and i ask you if have some info ,links where can give good eplantion how recreate this effect or some advice.

Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Cheers

Comment: That site should win awards for usability sacrificed on the altar of pretty

Comment: I must admit it is very pretty, and reminds me of flow. They even went for the overkill with the minimap with your position in the bottom left, incase you want to imagine you're playing asteroids while looking. Hell, it took me a few minutes to realize there were even links at the top.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your fast response and good advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the parallax a effect. [Here's a link](http://carsonified.com/blog/design/how-to-recreate-silverbacks-parallax-effect/) to a slightly different version to show you how it can be achieved in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really old but effective technique called Parallax Scrolling. You can probably get started with the theory on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

They have different layers of shapes that appear to be at different depths.

This is done by making the ones that are "further back" lighter (or more transparent), and by making them move slower.

This is a common technique used in 2D scrolling video games.

You can do the same thing in WPF by varying the speed at which things move.

Answer (score 0):

google for parallex scrolling. it was used in old games to fake 3d (scrolling mountains, trees and stars at different speeds)